# Creating a formatted, ordered pair in a single cell using Google Sheets functions

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to do something like a Google Sheets array, but have it display in a single cell.

Given a column of data (grades, for example):

```
={MAX(A1:A10), MIN(A1:A10)}
```

where the output inside of a single cell would look like (High Score, Low Score).

This currently works, but displays the array across two side by side cells. I wouldn't mind if they displayed on top of each other, if one cell isn't possible. Is either of these options possible?

Comment: Ugh, I never look at documentation for long enough. I found it {max ; min} using semi-colon.

Comment: Turn your comment into an answer as: *[Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)*. This way others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you need is:

```
=MAX(A1:A10)&", "&MIN(A1:A10)
```

Comment: @rocksNwaves vertically in one cell would be: `=MAX(A1:A10)&","&CHAR(10)&MIN(A1:A10)`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer I accepted, the following works in the case where you want to arrange the array vertically:

```
={MAX(A1:A10) ; MIN(A1:A10)}
```